# Unsupported top level event type "onGestureHandlerStateChange dispatched in iphone X

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios, react-navigation-drawer

I am facing an issue in `react-navigation-drawer`.

```
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.16",
"react-navigation": "^3.3.2"
```

This two version is installed. A drawer is working properly in Android and iPhone 5S. But, when I ran the app in iPhone X, it's throw error when I open drawer through gesture.

> Unsupported top level event type "onGestureHandlerStateChange" dispatched

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From this `react-native-gesture-handler` [issue comment](https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/320#issuecomment-443815828) by [balthazar](https://github.com/balthazar):

> Because my navigators were created asynchronously, the handler was registered too late and thus throwing this error. I fixed the issue by simply doing:
>
> ```
> import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
> ```
>
> at the top of my `index.js`

By `index.js`, balthazar is referring to your app's entrypoint – but I guess that the important thing is that it is imported before your first usage of `react-native-gesture-handler`.

Comment: you saved my live :)

Answer (score 9):

If your RN version is above 0.60+

In my case, you should firstly add `import 'react-native-gesture-handler';` in your top `index.js` file.

Then upgrade your `react-native-gesture-handler` to version  `>= 1.5.1` because the maintainer fixed a crash problem in IOS and you can see the closed issue here [issue#320](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/320)

Comment: This was it! Thanks!

Comment: That's awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Downgrade to `v1.0.14` fixes the issue for me

Comment: Thanks! This fixed it for me on RN `59`!

Comment: But it doesn't fix the issue for ***RN versions > 0.60***

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal For RN0.60 >, need to use the import fix as commented by Jamie